Symfony tests not calling my LoginSubscriber
I'm using Symfony 6.4, and I have a LoginSubcriber which sets some additional session data depending on the authenticated user's account setup. This additional session data is essential for the running of the site.
My subscriber is registered in /config/services.yaml as such:
services:
  ...
  App\EventListener\LoginSubscriber:
    tags: [ name: kernel.event_subscriber ]

And it works perfectly when logging in via a browser.
My issue comes when testing. If I call login $client->loginUser($user), then my LoginSubscriber is never called, which makes subsequent requests not work properly because they don't have the correct session data setup within the LoginSubscriber.
As a way around this, I changed my test to log the user in manually by going through the full flow:
class FullSearchTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testPartialSearchRequiresThreeCharacters(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('SIGN IN')->form([
            '_username' => 'admin',
            '_password' => 'password',
        ]);
        $client->submit($form);
        $client->followRedirects();

        $client->request('GET', '/search', [
            'firstName' => 'fo',
        ]);

        $this->assertResponseIsUnprocessable();
    }
}

I run the test with phpunit like php bin/phpunit
The route /search requires the ROLE_USER, so they must be logged in.
I guess my question is, is there a way to get $client->loginUser($user); to trigger the LoginSubscriber, and if not, is my manual login workaround efficient in the long term, as I add more and more tests?

This question is similar to: How to test custom event listener. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think your concept of loginUser is wrong. It's not trying to login a user, it's setting the application that this user is logged in, no matter what.  You are specifying a "background" (in BEHAT/Cucumber terms).  If you want to have your event listeners to be executed, you could for example create a Trait, and call $this->loginAnAdmin() and run that submit logic.  This way you are really using functional testing without duplicating your code over and over. Or use that method to set the "background" manually without using the Controller.

I think you're right. By the sounds of it, it's probably more akin to the name of Laravel's "actingAs" method which I'm more used to, rather than as you say, actually logging the user in. Creating the trait/method is a good idea, and one I'm already using, I'd just extracted it for simplicity here
